# Is it possible to resize the relative node size in ggrraph?

Tags: r, social-networking, ggraph, tidygraph

New to `R`; did my best with the rendering my question with the help of with `reprex`.

I have a network with nodes sized by degree, using the `ggraph` package.

The plotted network doesn't look great because some of the nodes are quite small.

I would like to increase the relative size of the nodes.

In `igraph`, I would increase the relative size of the nodes with something like:

```
plot(df, vertex.cex=degree*5)
```

I've tried something similar in `ggraph` (in the rerpex below) but the result is a multiplication of the *degree value* rather than an increase in the relative *size* of the node.

I would like to stick to the `ggraph` package if only because of the tidy/grammar approach and to manage the (oh so very steep) learning curve (although I could be convinced otherwise if anyone has some thoughts on the two packages).

The examples below don't have attached plots because my reputation isn't high enough to post images. But if I've done this right, the reprex should do what it's suppose to do.

```r
#load libraries
library(tidygraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tidygraph'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(ggraph)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
# Creating a data frame
df <- rbind(c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1),
            c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0),
            c(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
            c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0),
            c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0),
            c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0),
            c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0),
            c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1),
            c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1))
# convert to matrix
df <- as.matrix(df) #convert to matrix df; columns as headings is part of the function
# convert to tbl_graph
df <- as_tbl_graph(df)

# plot network; nodes sized by degree; nodes too small
df %>% 
  mutate(degree = centrality_degree()) %>% 
  ggraph(layout = 'kk') + 
  geom_node_point(aes(size = degree))+
  geom_edge_link()

# tried multiplying degree by a value as below; changes the 
# value of the degrees and leaves node size unchanged.
df %>% 
  mutate(degree = centrality_degree()) %>% 
  ggraph(layout = 'kk') + 
  geom_node_point(aes(size = 2*degree))+
  geom_edge_link()
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution having a look to this link: [Network Visualizations in R](http://mr.schochastics.net/netVizR.html)

The key is to add `scale_size_continuous` in the pipeline for your plot. I have tried this option:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(degree = centrality_degree()) %>% 
  ggraph(layout = 'kk') + 
  geom_node_point(aes(size = degree)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(2, 5)) +
  geom_edge_link()
```